# Assign values from an array to specific PHP variables

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am trying to use PHP to select values from a SQL Server DB and assign values to specific parameters.

The table I am selecting from looks like this:

```
**ColumnName1 ColumnName2**
DataRow1Col1, DataRow1Col2
DataRow2Col1, DataRow2Col2
DataRow3Col1, DataRow3Col2
DataRow4Col1, DataRow4Col2
```

I am trying to create a variable that will be equal to DataRow3Col2 which always has a ColumnName1 = DataRow3Col1.

Is this possible?

Here is what I have so far:

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM Table where id = {$ID}";
  $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $trpConn, $sql );
  if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
  }

  $data = array(); 
  while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

    $data[] = $row; 
  } 

  sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
```

Thank you

Comment: I want to create a variable that says $DataRow3Col1 and it will have a value equal to DataRow3Col2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table where id = {$ID}";
  $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $trpConn, $sql );
  if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
  }

  $data = array(); 
  while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

    $data[$row['ColumnName1']] = $row['ColumnName2']; 
  }

  sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);

  extract($data);

  echo $DataRow1Col1;
  // The Output is: DataRow1Col2
```

Comment: This seems like its on the right track but then how do I use $data to get just one value? Now it has all the rows.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - extract isn't create any new variables for me. I confirmed this by using: print_r(array_keys(get_defined_vars()));

Comment: @AAA, It should work. in this case, I can say you would have $DataRow1Col1 equals to 'DataRow1Col2'

Comment: by any chance would this be different if I had spaces? IE: ${Data Row1 Col1}? Thank you!!

Comment: The exact error I am getting is: PHP Notice: Undefined variable: Data Row1 Col1

Comment: @AAA, you would get error or notice if the variable names were different. you have to use your exact column name. and if your value has space, it couldn't be extracted. As it's the programming logic.

Comment: finally got this working :) thank you @Mojtaba! I changed the SQL to use a replace() to remove spaces and it worked!